# how to find -l or --log-file string in a file and store absolute path passed with that as a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

how to find -l or --log-file string in a file and store absolute path passed with that as a variable ?

Sample file 1:-

```
$ cat server.log
server_options='-l /tmp/server_log'
```

Sample file 2:-

```
$ cat server.log
server_options='--log-file=/tmp/server1_log'
```

Requirement

if -l or --log-file is found in server_options variable then find the absolute path of the file and store it in a variable

Note:- 
1. Don't consider lines starting with "#"
2. if "-l" option is specified between the -l and absolute path there will be a space and if "--log-file" is specified between the "--log-file" and absolute path there will be a equal to sign "="

for example

```
server_options='-l /tmp/server_log'
server_options='--log-file=/tmp/server1_log'
```

Desired output of the sample 1 file stored in a variable "LOG_FILE"

```
$ echo $LOG_FILE
/tmp/server_log
```

Desired output of the sample 2 file stored in a variable "LOG_FILE"

```
$ echo $LOG_FILE
/tmp/server1_log
```

Tried:-

```
$ grep "^[^#;]" server.log | awk '/\-\l|/{ print $2 }'
/tmp/server_log'
```

Need more reliable way to achieve this

Comment: Update the question that there could be more flags following `-l /tmp/server_log` in that variable

Comment: And _don't_ use variable to store options, use an array!

Comment: With GNU grep: `LOG_FILE=$(grep -Po '(-l|--log-file) \K.*(?=.)' file)`

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus: You should post it as answer, and add `^[^#].*` before, as OP wants to ignore lines starting with `#`

Comment: @Cyrus how to ignore lines that starts with "#" with the one-liner you posted

Answer (score 1):

Other than `awk`, there is also a `cut` command which can have similar result. For example:

```
grep "-l|--log-file" server.log | cut -d'\'' -f1 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

`cut -d'\'' -f1` = cut by `'` character, choose 2nd string

`cut -d' ' -f1` = cut by "space" character, choose 2nd string

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "^[^#;]" server.log |grep -Po '(-l|--log-file) \K.*(?=.)'
```

Comment: You could just combine it as `grep -Po '^[^#;].*(-l|--log-file) \K.*(?=.)' /etc/ddn/ime/ime-server.conf`

Comment: if "-l" option is specified between the -l and absolute path there will be a space and if "--log-file" is specified between the "--log-file" and absolute path there will be a equal to sign "="

Comment: server_options='-l /tmp/server_log'
server_options='--log-file=/tmp/server1_log'

Comment: and this one liner doesn't work with "--log-file" option

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit long shot, but understandable

```
egrep '\-l|\-\-log\-file' server.log | grep -v ^# | gawk -F"'" '{print $2}' | cut -d" " -f2
```